# Event handlers in fanybox are not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

**Description :**

The images are opening perfectly .. but the event handler's response is nothing... I don't know what's wrong

**HTML**

```
<a class="fancybox-effects-a" href="DSC_0453.JPG" id = "po" title="Something...">

    <img  src="1399665890_143822.ico" alt="" />

</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".fancybox-effects-a").fancybox({
                "onComplete": function () {
            // close fancybox after 3 seconds
            setTimeout(function () {
                $.fancybox.close();
            }, 3000)
        },
                helpers: {
                    title : {
                        type : 'inside'
                    },
                    overlay : {
                        speedOut : 0
                    }
                }
            });

            });
```

event handlers like `onStart` , `onComplete` , `onCancel` etc not anyone of them seems to be working.. Anybody knows why ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the callback methods are different in **fancybox2**. It uses **beforeLoad**, **afterShow**, etc. Please see fancybox2's documentation [here](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs).